# Use containsLocation with Fusiontable point layer and drawn polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to be able to select all points from a fusiontable layer that are within a drawn polygon in google maps api 3.

I know in Google Maps API v3 there is the containsLocation method in geometry library, but I dont know how to extract lat/lon from the fusiontable layer and make a loop that will scan over all the markers in the layer.

Thank you very much if you can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data from the FusionTable using the [FusionTables API v1](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started).

[Example that extracts kml "Points" from a FusionTable and displays them as markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=14.620282&lng=-90.504716&zoom=12&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20%20geometry,%20name,%20description%20FROM&tableid=1npi-QWwoZ6LP_9wwHiwiG2omzMm6R9Qoj5aMjkM)